# Stretching div background image for IE7

Tags: html, background, internet-explorer-7, stretch, css

I'm stuck at making **IE7** stretch background image for div, it does not support CSS3 `background-size`.
Basically I need [image fitting red area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gql45.jpg).

Div may have different height depending on content. That is why I had no luck with [img faking background](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm), I don't know how to set height.

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search came up with (I haven't tested it, but Google is a lovely good friend):

```
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  img#bg{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
  #content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
  }
</style>
```

Edit: Derp.  Forgot the sample HTML

```
</head>

  <body>

     <img src="size-bg.jpg" alt="background image" id="bg" />
     <div id="content">Your website content.</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Linked from: http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.com/2011/01/ie-78-stretching-background-image-to.html

Comment: Thanks! I saw this one. It draws background for the whole page, but I only need it for div. Here [http://i.stack.imgur.com/gql45.jpg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gql45.jpg) is the example. My problem is that picture with height:100% makes div too big.

Comment: What about resizing the picture to the size you need and then set it as a background-url for just the div? Granted, it's a hack solution...

Comment: Yeap, I did it that way. I put `img` with `display:none` style. Then in document ready I resize image to the div size and set `display:block`. Dirty but working solution :)